# get current activity view after setContentView

Tags: android

i'm using a listview with an onclickitemlistener when i'm clicking on an item of the listview it change the view with setContentView ( from view_list.xml to view_detail.xml)

how can i know what is my current view of my activity (list or detail).

in my onBackPressed() i want to switch to the view_list if i'm in the view_detail
if i'm already in my view_list layout i want to finish() the activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( ?????? !== findViewById(R.id.view_list_id));
          setContentView(R.layout.view_list); 
    else
          finish();
    }
```

i could use an activity instead of just changing layout but i feel like it could work this way.

thanks.

Comment: in short, dont do it this way

Comment: why it's not recommended ?

Comment: This is *exactly* why Android introduced `Fragment`s. Use Fragments. It's less coding for you, as the fragment manager handles the backstack for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the content view of an `Activity`.

If you want to have a List and Detail page, use [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead. This will also allow you to display the list as a side pane on tablets.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( null == findViewById(R.id.view_list_id));
    setContentView(R.layout.view_list); 
else{
    finish();
}
```

Hope this is what you want. This will check if the view contains a view with id `view_list_id` if so it will finish the activity otherwise replace the view. As the suggestion says this way is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be a Master/Detail flow:

You can easily acheive it if you are using Eclipse with ADT. Just create a new project with master detail Template.

Some helpful tutorials regarding this:

- [Creating master detail flow.](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-blog-reader-android-app/exploring-the-masterdetail-template/creating-a-project-using-the-masterdetail-template-2)
- [Getting started with masterdetail.](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/getting-started-with-fragments-and-the-support-library/)